# MySQL/Python fetching numbers omits zeros

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

For a project, I need to send a transaction to a R-Pi that uses a string of 8 values. For example:

```
boardone='00000001'
```

This boardone tells another program to open or close relays. I have been successful in storing the whole 'string' of values in the database, but when using fetch is does not work. Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb as mariadb

connection = mariadb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", 
passwd="secretpass", db="secret")

cursor = connection.cursor ()

#We want to recieve the newest transaction from the database 
#One other way would be sorting by transaction ID 
cursor.execute ("select Column2, Column3 from connectiontest where start
(select MAX(start) from connectiontest)")

received= cursor.fetchone() 

cursor.close ()
connection.close ()
```

Column2 and Column3 and stored in the database (at the max timestamp) currently as:

```
(00000001,00000001)
```

Where Column2 and Column3 are unsigned, zerofilled, integers.

When printing received:

```
received
Out[410]: (1, 1)
```

What is the proper syntax to correct this? Is it a problem with the fetch command or something else?

Comment: `Column2` and `Column3` should be `varchar` in order to store the leading zeroes

Comment: zerofill is really more a display trait, usually only seen in directly displayed query results. Since integer types do not inherently have any sort of padding property, this is usually omitted from query results in most environments. _Similar to what I expect would happen if you assigned boardone that value without the quotes._

Comment: @Hackerman Thank you so much, looks like that was the solution. I remember trying to make them varchar's earlier but something went wrong, but looks good now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Uueerdo okay great, that is really important to know since I will continue working with data of this format. Thank you !!

Comment: Glad to help @SwankyTigers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it

```
INT(8) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL
```

[*Reference*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html)